# How to get iOS to talk to .NET web service

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having issues connecting to this webservice, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
- (void)startRetrievingHotels 
{    
    //Create the web service URL
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.stratexlive.com/tenants/commercialbank/_vti_bin/stratexws.asmx"];

    //Create the web service request
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *requestString = [self buildHotelListRequest];
    NSLog(@"%@", requestString );

    [request setDelegate:self]; 
    [request setUsername:@"asdfasdf@asdfasdf.com"];
    [request setPassword:@"asdfasdfasdfasdf$"];
    [request appendPostData:[[self buildHotelListRequest] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //Set the xml request
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (NSString *)buildHotelListRequest
{


    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
    @"<GetUserName xmlns=\"https://www.sdf.com/\" />"];

    NSLog(@"HOTEL LIST REQUEST: %@", result);

    return result;
}
```

This is the response I get:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope
> xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Header><soap12:Upgrade
> xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap12:SupportedEnvelope
> qname="soap:Envelope"
> xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
> 
> <soap12:SupportedEnvelope qname="soap12:Envelope"
> xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" />
> 
> </soap12:Upgrade></soap:Header><soap:Body><soap:Fault>
> 
> <faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode><faultstring>Possible SOAP
> version mismatch: Envelope namespace https://www.stratexsystems.com/
> was unexpected. Expecting
> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.</faultstring>
> 
> <detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body>
> 
> </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Cant you use NSURLConnection???

Comment: @H2CO3 have updated question.  Inder - my requests are going to get more complex so am more familiar with ASIHTTREQUEST

Comment: And now I'm bored scrolling horizontally that 100k XML response. Please *indent*.

Comment: This is a soap web service and I dont know much about this.. sorry

Comment: @TheLearner it seems that the webservice expect some kind of version info, but you're not including it in the request. Do the docs mention it?

Comment: You may have no choice, but if at all possible switch to a REST-based interface. Talking SOAP on iOS is a serious pain and you are likely to have constant problems like this.

Comment: gsoap is also a viable solution. Hand-coding SOAP in ObjC is insanely tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read about soap and found that you are missing something.
Here is some of info but I'm not sure where to put the username and password.
Hope you will figure it out.

```
NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\
<soap:Body>\
<GetUserName xmlns=\"https://www.stratexsystems.com/\" />\
</soap:Body>\
</soap:Envelope>";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.stratexlive.com/tenants/commercialbank/_vti_bin/stratexws.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"https://www.stratexsystems.com/GetUserName" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: You're on the right track here. The underlying problem is that you must construct the *entire* SOAP message, including the envelope. The OP's request only included the body. I cannot stress how much of a pain hand-building and hand-decoding SOAP in ObjC is for complex requests. If switching to REST is impossible, then I recommend using gsoap rather than hand-building this stuff.